# Home link inside sidebar. Sidebar opens on click. Clicking home should open sidebar or home?

Tags: interaction-design, user-behavior, user-expectation, sidebar

I have a page layout where the sidebar occupies the whole height. The sidebar is a list of different *Project links*, and the top element in the list is the *Page Home link* (*a* in this case).

The sidebar can be opened and closed. When closed, **clicking anywhere in the sidebar opens it**. When opened clicking in any element in the list will load it (wether it is a project or the Home) and close the sidebar.

The way I have it right now the logo acts with the same logic. So when the sidebar is closed clicking the logo will open the sidebar. And when opened clicking it will load the Home page.

My question is if this interaction is correct. **When a user clicks in that logo should I understand he wants to open the Sidebar or open the Home?** Even if the answer is probably most user will understand it to be the Home, should I keep opening the sidebar in the first click in case the user wanted to open the sidebar (as they can still open the Home with a second click)?

[image: sidebar]

Comment: Checkout the [Fuse Demo](http://fuse-angular-material.withinpixels.com/dashboard-project). They have something similar, but when the mouse enters the sidenav region, the sidenav automatically opens, that is if you haven't locked the sidenav.

Comment: Thanks @Tory. I actually used to have it open on hover but found it better to rely on click. Some of the reasoning related to [this answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/102389/menu-with-dropdown-root-element-clickable/102393#102393) I wrote, also it created some unexpected behaviours.

Comment: @Alvaro, posted the answer. Let me know your views. Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pointer cursor alone doesn't seem like a clear enough indicator that clicking the logo or sidebar will open a menu. Try adding a caret icon (>) or menu peek effect with Javascript to allude to the nature of the interaction.

Most users are used to the logo as a link to home, so I would recommend that you don't shake that expectation up needlessly, especially since you have a clickable menu area right below the logo. Just add something that makes that menu obvious.

Whether you keep the same behavior for both elements or not, the menu-opening click should be more clear.